# Zariski open set of linear forms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $I$ be a graded homogeneous ideal over $k[x_1, ... ,x_n]$ and $h$ a linear form, let $H$ be the corresponding hyperplane and $I_H$ the restriction of $I$ to $H$.
I am looking for  a Zariski open set $U$ of linear forms such that, $\mathrm{in}(I:h^k)_H$ be constant on $U$. Where  $\mathrm{in}(J)$, denotes the initial ideal of ideal $J$, with respect to rlex monomial order.

Comment: Does $in$ denote the initial ideal wrt some monomial order? Otherwise you can assume wlog that $h=x_1$, say.

Comment: yes, $\mathrm{in}(I)$,denotes the initial ideal of ideal $I$, with respect to rlex monomial order.